# How to find all Orthogonal vectors to one vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, orthogonality

I'm doing home work and I'm not really understanding what I'm supposed to do with this problem.

I have vector $\mathbf{v}=(1,-1,-1,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. I'm supposed to find all orthogonal vectors. I dont really know how to create a matrix from this.

I started by making $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4)$. And then multiplying $\mathbf{u}$ with $\mathbf{v}$ would just basically give me $(u_1,-u_2,-u_3,u_4)$ which seems too simple and wrong. Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Hint: Can you write the orthogonality condition as linear equation?

Comment: You can think of the vector $\bf{v}$ is a matrix of size $1 \times 4$ (i.e. 1 row and 4 columns). Then finding all orthogonal vectors is equivalent to finding the general solution to $A \bf{x} = \bf{0}$, where the matrix $A = \bf{v}$

Answer (score 1):

The inner product of $v$ and $u$ is given by

$$u_1-u_2-u_3+u_4.$$

Hence

$$ v \perp u \iff u_1-u_2-u_3+u_4=0.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I don't really understand how will the scalar product of u and v will be zero if each term of u has the same sign as v. Because negative terms will turn positive and then the sum will be greater than zero, meaning that they are not orthogonal? Sorry im just really confused.